# Symfony2 Expaned table with checkboxes form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, checkbox, twig

I have a table which contains information for example "ID", "Category", "Name" and "Action". Now I want to improve the table with checkboxes which enables the user to choose multiple rows and to delete them in one step.

My problem: I have created a form with the form-builder:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('id', 'entity', array(
                'required'  => false,
                'class'    => 'AppBundle:Task',
                'property' => 'id',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true
            ))
            ->add('add', 'submit', array('label' => 'Add'));
    }
```

This form is send to the twig-html with the table which contains the data for the table.

```
{% if table|length > 0 %}
        {{ form_start(addForm) }}
        {{ form_errors(addForm) }}
        <table class='result' border=1>
            <th></th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
            {% for item in table %}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    {% for entity in addForm.id %}
                        {% if entity.vars.value == item.id %}
                            {{ form_widget(entity.vars.form) }}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.category }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.action }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

As you can see my solution has to search in a for loop for the correct ID of the form-item and place them.

My problem now: I do not feel comfortable with this solution - is there a more easier way to display a table containing several columns and checkboxes?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Also have the problem that I get the following error after selecting some checkboxes:

```
Neither the property "id" nor one of the methods "addId()"/"removeId()", "setId()", "id()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\XXXXXX".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should better use the [collection form type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) rather then the entity type because you will be able to use a custom form and twig template for each record of the database table. In this [explanation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) you will learn how to remove or add one row. Adding checkboxes to provide batch actions will then be an additional javascript solution